# In Swift, can you split a string by another string, not just a character?

Tags: swift, split, swift4

In Swift, it's easy to split a string on a character and return the result in an array.  What I'm wondering is if you can split a string by another string instead of just a single character, like so...

```
let inputString = "This123Is123A123Test"
let splits = inputString.split(onString:"123")
// splits == ["This", "Is", "A", "Test"]
```

I think `NSString` may have a way to do as much, and of course I could roll my own in a `String` extension, but I'm looking to see if Swift has something natively.

Comment: @AhmadF, this is not a duplicate of splitting a string into an array.  This is specifically splitting a string *on a string* instead of a character.  As such, could you please remove the dup vote.  Thanks! :)

Comment: If you tried to `cmd` and click on `components(separatedBy: "123")`, you would note that the type of the `separator` parameter is [StringProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol) which means that it could take a single character or a string :)

Comment: Yes, but I wasn't looking at that. I was looking at the 'split' function which doesn't have that option, hence my question and it's specific request. I saw that other question before posting this but disregarded it because that specifically asked about a character whereas I needed a string delimiter.  Again, this ***question*** is not a duplicate even if the answer is the same, just as you can use a coffee cup for both coffee and hot chocolate. Same cup. Different reason for using it. Again, please remove the dup vote.  Thanks!

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
import Foundation

let inputString = "This123Is123A123Test"
let splits = inputString.components(separatedBy: "123")
```

Comment: Awesome! Even better than I was hoping as unlike `string.split` which returns `[String.SubSequence]`, this returns `[String]` which I ultimately need anyway! (I used to have to add `.map(String.init)` at the end. Now I don't have to!

Comment: Thank you.. I was pulling my hair out over this.

Comment: Thank you! this is it

Answer (score -1):

You mean this?

```
let developer = "XCode Swift"
let array = developer.characters.split{" "}.map(String.init)

array[0] // XCode
array[1] // Swift
```

Comment: You don't use `characters` in Swift 4. And this doesn't do what is being asked for in the question.

Comment: The space can replace it by "123"

Comment: Your edit doesn't compile in Swift 4 and no, you can't replace the space with "123" since `split` only accepts one `Character`.